# Mobiscroll on normal web page - example - usability?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, usability, jsfiddle, mobiscroll

http://demo.mobiscroll.com/

Mobiscroll is a new date and time picker which dramatically increases usability on touch devices.

My intention is to create a web app which will have responsive UI ( aka works on Tablets,Touch Phones and Normal Desktops ) and I want to use Mobiscroll,as it seem to be working well on desktop browsers  as well.

I was interested in knowing fair it would be to use Mobiscroll in a normal web page ?
Would is create pain / poor usability ?

And example of Mobiscroll on normal web page by some expert will be great ! ( jsfiddle ?? )
Example shall portray  best practice , if any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you choose to do, there are some usability concerns you should take into account.

1. Make sure you add to the experience, by making the life of the user easier, not harder (that's why mobiscroll works good on a touch device).
2. Make sure you don't lock the user into a corner by forcing him to do something that he's not familiar with. For example... you can provide a textbox for entering the date & time, and have a "show picker" button, which invokes the mobiscroll picker.

You can always make your app intelligent enough to figure out where it's being used and invoke mobiscroll only on tablets/smartphones.